# Как вывести данные из многомерного массива

Tags: php, php7

Есть массив такого вида:

```
Array
(
   [United States] => Array
      ( 
         [National Collegiate Athletic Association (NCAA)] Array
                                                        (
                                                               [0] => 334590962
                                                               [1] => 334591241
                                                        )
         [National Collegiate Athletic Association (NCAA). Women] Array
                                                        (
                                                               [0] => 334591994
                                                        )
      )
   [World] => Array
      ( 
         [Short Football 4x4] Array
                          (
                               [0] => 334595637
                               [1] => 334596291
                          )
      )
)
```

Каким циклом можно вывести лиги (National Collegiate Athletic Association (NCAA), Short Football 4x4, ...) и отдельно вывести все матчи (334590962, 334591241, 334591994, ...)

Всю голову сломал, смог только выводить все страны.

Comment: Циклом `foreach`

Answer (score 0):

В два прохода вот так. А если в один то придется запоминать данные о матчах во вспомогательный массив. Но это чревато тем, что при больших объемах данных может не хватить памяти для выделения под этот массив.

```php
<?php
$allMatches =[
   'United States' => [ 
         'National Collegiate Athletic Association (NCAA)' => [
                                                                0 => 334590962,
                                                                1 => 334591241
                                                              ],
         'National Collegiate Athletic Association (NCAA).Women' => [                                                       
                                                               0 => 334591994
                                                        ]
      ],
   'World' => [
       
         'Short Football 4x4' => 
                          [
                               0 => 334595637,
                               1 => 334596291
                          ]
      ]

];

$countriesList = array_keys( $allMatches );

echo "Leagues list:\n";
echo "------------\n";
foreach( $countriesList as $country ) {
    $leaguesList = array_keys( $allMatches[$country] );
    foreach( $leaguesList as $league ) {
        echo $league."\n";
    }
}
echo "\nMatches list:\n";
echo "------------\n";
foreach( $countriesList as $country ) {
    $leaguesList = array_keys( $allMatches[$country] );
    foreach( $leaguesList as $league ) {
        $matchesList = $allMatches[$country][$league];
        foreach( $matchesList as $match ) {
            echo $match."\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Если вид массивов не будет меняться (расширяться во вложениях), то как то так

```
foreach ($allMatches as $k=>$v){ // $k - Страна
    foreach ($v as $k1=>$v1){ // $k1 - Клуб или что это
      foreach ($v1 as $k2=>$v2){ // $v2 - значения циферок
          echo $k.' - '.$k1.' - '.$v2."\n";
    }
    }
    
}
```

Результат:

```
United States - National Collegiate Athletic Association (NCAA) - 334590962
United States - National Collegiate Athletic Association (NCAA) - 334591241
United States - National Collegiate Athletic Association (NCAA).Women - 334591994
World - Short Football 4x4 - 334595637
World - Short Football 4x4 - 334596291
```

Чтоб по отдельности все вывести, думаю сообразите